# Local Storage Not Working When Applying Dark Mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply Dark Mode To My Website. I am using the code given below to do so.

```
!(function () {
  var t,
    e = document.getElementById("darkSwitch");
  if (e) {
    (t =
      null !== localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") &&
      "dark" === localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch")),
      (e.checked = t)
        ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark")
        : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme"),
      e.addEventListener("change", function (t) {
        e.checked
          ? (document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark"),
            localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"))
          : (document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "light"),
            localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"));
      });
  }
})();
```

You can check it out here **http://anayaadventure.com/**

Everything is working fine but the problem is now suppose I turn the dark mode off and I refresh the page, then the page again loads in dark mode. Why is this happening and how can I solve it.

Thanks for any kind of help in advence.

Comment: is the script is loaded before the DOM?
make sure that the script is loaded after the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never set localstorage back to "light" in the toggle-event

```
   e.checked
      ? (document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark"),
        localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark")) //set to dark
      : (document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "light"),
        localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark")); //set item to "light" instead of "dark" ?
```

And if you edit the local storage value manually to "light" it goes back to lightmode
so i think you want to change the last line to localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "light"));

Addition to that i like the layout and design of the site!

Comment: Yeah it solved my problem. Thanks for your help. Also, thanks for your Complement. I am really happy to know that you liked my work. 